# Regex On Text Producing Empty Value

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use regex on a line of text to get the values of Name=.

```
 var match = Regex.Match(textR, @"\bName='([^']*?)'");
```

The value of textR in question is

```
$MPElement[Name="System.WorkItem.Incident.Queue.Tier2.Unassigned.View.Header_Id"]$
```

But it just brings back an `{}`

Comment: Why would it match? You're looking for single quotes and your string uses double quotes.

Comment: did you want to match `System.WorkItem.Incident.Queue.Tier2.Unassigned.View.Header_Id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
resultString = Regex.Match(yourstring, @"(?<=Name="")[^""]+").Value;
```

- The lookbehind `(?<=Name=")` ensures that we are preceded by `Name="`
- The negative character class `[^"]` matches any character that is not a double quote
- The `+` quantifier matches such chars one or more times

Comment: Couldn't do it for 8 mins it said not a problem reg ex still escapes me at the in.

Comment: Thanks, glad it works. :) Is something still unclear?

Comment: I need to do this also budy to get whats have after type?

"$Context/Property[Type='CoreIncident!System.WorkItem.Incident']/Status$"

Comment: `resultString = Regex.Match(s1, "(?<=Type=')[^']+").Value;`

Comment: No worries, catch you next time :)